# location info of objects not changing in any frame for physics simulation (but their position changes)

Tags: animation, rigid-body-simulation

I am new to blender and using it for generating a dataset for another problem that I am working on. I use physics simulation to make objects fall. The problem I am facing is that the object.location value does not update after simulating. I can see that the objects did move in 3d view. Do I have to do something different to get the location in the last frame? (need python solution for this) I am using the following code for simulating

```py
def simulate(start_frame=1, end_frame=200):
   for i in range(start_frame, end_frame + 1):
       bpy.context.scene.frame_set(i)
       bpy.context.scene.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer to my question in case someone else needs it, global translation can be accessed as follows.

```py
bpy.data.objects['obj'].matrix_world.translation
```